# Changing input fields background when its edited

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I'm currently working on admin panel for my project, and wondering how can I create input form, what would change its background color when user edited text in it. I need it in big tables to see what cells was edited. May be it must be some javascripts or just pure css/html

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of your form:

```
<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" /><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</form>​
```

You can use focus selector in css if you want to see the actual input edit
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XFNd4/)
in your CSS:

```
 input:focus
    {
    background-color:yellow;
    }
```

Or if you want to see all your input edit you can try with jquery like this:
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XFNd4/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("input[type=text]").change(function() {
           $(this).css("background","#c7c7c7");
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted a piece of code that changed the background color of the input fields with the values changed, not the field currently in focus.

Answer (score 2):

This would do the trick!

`<input type="text" onblur="javascript:if(this.value!=original_value){this.style.backgroundColor='red';}else{this.style.backgroundColor='';}" />`

Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I use this bit of jquery to change the background color when a field is edited

```
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('textarea, input, select').change(function() {
            $(this).css({'background' : '#D6FFD6'});
         });
    });
```